# Symfony2 on Cygwin - PHP segmentation fault

Tags: php, symfony, cygwin

I struggle to be able to run PHP client line interface on Cygwin. I receive constantly `Segmentation fault` error. But some of functions are correctly done - I cannot say when does it happen.

If somebody had this error, please give me any clue to correctly run PHP CLI under cygwin.

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**

I Receive stackdump, but I don't know if it tells anything:

```
Exception: STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION at eip=603B7AC6
eax=0000000A ebx=FFE42FFF ecx=002853E0 edx=FFE43000 esi=00000000 edi=FFE43000
ebp=002853E2 esp=00285240 program=C:\cygwin\bin\php.exe, pid 10056, thread main
cs=0023 ds=002B es=002B fs=0053 gs=002B ss=002B
Stack trace:
Frame     Function  Args
002853E2  603B7AC6 (022A018F, 02D40284, 0348030B, 0374034D)
00040002  00F30055 (00340000, 01E00000, 020C0000, 00360000)
```

Moreover I tried to limit in php.ini

```
pcre.recursion_limit=1000
```

- no effect.

It crashes every time when I work with client line interface. If I run it through Apache2 there is no problem.

How can I debug it effectively?

**EDIT**

I run it with php-cgi, where I receive the html output with error description:

```
ContextErrorException: Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in ...
```

Having this information I guess that there is a problem with input arguments. If I run scripts without arguments from console I don't receive `segmentation fault`.

This is Symfony framework and those scripts run like a charm on windows and ubuntu on console. So I guess:
 - there is something wrong with PHP settings
 - there is something wrong with console on Cygwin

Any idea how can I debug it more?

Comment: that's pretty vague.  Segmentation faults are from accessing invalid memory addresses.  They can be from lots of causes, including your cpu overheating, no way to tell without more info.  Does it always crash in the same place, or at random places?

Comment: Thanks for your question. I put some additional information in EDIT. Maybe there is some way to effectively debug it ?

Comment: pcre is the Perl Compatible Regular Expression library, that won't make a difference here.  Could it be permissions?  Is apache also running under cygwin?  Could it be a permissions issue?  I don't know enough about Windows to trace to there.  You should change the subject line to mention the status_access_violation error, maybe someone had encountered it and knows what it is.

Comment: I don't know what is used inside those scripts, because they're framework basic scripts and as I wrote in EDIT they working fine in native operating systems. In fact this case is Symfony framework under cygwin. So I will change the topic and add some tags. I also have added some additional info in the second EDIT. Apache is running, but without apache is the same. When I user php-cgi to run the script I get an error with invalid arguments array, since scripts are provided with arguments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After long hours of useless research I end up with removing php5 and php from Cygwin and mapping there standalone PHP for Windows.

For anyone facing this problem:

1. Uninstall all "PHP" group of extensions for cygwin
2. Run cygwin
3. `rm -f /usr/bin/php.exe`
4. `rm -rf /usr/share/php`
5. Download and install brand new PHP for Windows
6. `ln -s /cygdrive/c/your/path/to/php/php.exe /usr/bin/php.exe`

So I don't know why this issue occured to me, but fresh native php for windows installation helped.

Comment: I couldn't figure out what was wrong either. But yes, installing a native windows PHP and linking it to cygwins bin folder worked.